# Algorithm for generating strings of +/-s with a specific property

Tags: algorithm, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, computer-science

I am interested in writing a function `generate(n,m)` which exhaustively generating strings of length `n(n-1)/2` consisting solely of `+`/`-` characters. These strings will then be transformed into an n × n symmetric (-1,0,1)-matrix in the following way:

```
toTriangle["+--+-+-++-"]  

{{1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1}}
```

```
toMatrix[%, 0] // MatrixForm

             | 0  1 -1 -1  1 |  
             | 1  0 -1  1 -1 |  
matrixForm = |-1 -1  0  1  1 |  
             |-1  1  1  0 -1 |
             | 1 -1  1 -1  0 |
```

Thus the given string represents the upper-right triangle of the matrix, which is then reflected to generate the rest of it.

> **Question**: How can I generate all `+`/`-` strings such that *the resulting matrix has precisely `m` -1's per row*?

For example, `generate(5,3)` will give all strings of length `5(5-1)/2 = 10` such that each row contains precisely three -1's.

I'd appreciate any help with constructing such an algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to generate *any* 5x5 matrix with precisely three -1's in each row?

Comment: In truth, I'm after `generate(74,32)`, however I'm not sure how computationally feasible that is... nonetheless, I'd like to use the algorithm for smaller cases too.

Comment: are you trying to generate all possibilities because you are trying to optimize something?

Comment: Truth is, I'm trying to generate 74 × 74 matrices which have only two eigenvalues... and this property significantly lessens the search space.

Comment: Are you not including 0 as an eigenvalue?

Comment: @JaredGoguen A zero eigenvalue would not be possible for matrices of this form.

Comment: I was finding that the eigenvalues of a 5x5 matrix were (e, e, -e, -e, 0).

Comment: I replaced images by text, because the use of images for text or code is discouraged on SO (they are not searchable and can't be interpreted by screenreaders).

Comment: @m69 Cheers for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the logic to generate every matrix for a given n and m. It's a bit convoluted, so I'm not sure how much faster than brute force an implementation would be; I assume the difference will become more pronounced for larger values.

*(The following will generate an output of zeros and ones for convenience, where zero represents a plus and a one represents a minus.)*

A square matrix where each row has m ones translates to a triangular matrix where these folded row/columns have m ones:

```
x 0 1 0 1    x 0 1 0 1    0          1        0      1
0 x 1 1 0                 x 1 1 0    1        1      0
1 1 x 0 0                            x 0 0    0      0
0 1 0 x 1                                     x 1    1
1 0 0 1 x                                            x
```

Each of these groups overlaps with all the other groups; choosing values for the first k groups means that the vertical part of group k+1 is already determined.

We start by putting the number of ones required per row on the diagonal; e.g. for (5,2) that is:

```
2 . . . .
  2 . . .
    2 . .
      2 .
        2
```

Then we generate every bit pattern with m ones for the first group; there are (n-1 choose m) of these, and they can be efficiently generated, e.g. with Gosper's hack.

```
(4,2)  ->  0011  0101  0110  1001  1010  1100
```

For each of these, we fill them in in the matrix, and subtract them from the numbers of required ones:

```
X 0 0 1 1
  2 . . .
    2 . .
      1 .
        1
```

and then recurse with the smaller triangle:

```
2 . . .
  2 . .
    1 .
      1
```

If we come to a point where some of the numbers of required ones on the diagonal are zero, e.g.:

```
2 . . .
  1 . .
    0 .
      1
```

then we can already put a zero in this column, and generate the possible bit patterns for fewer columns; in the example that would be (2,2) instead of (3,2), so there's only one possible bit pattern: 11. Then we distribute the bit pattern over the columns that have a non-zero required count under them:

```
2 . 0 .    X 1 0 1
  1 . .      0 . .
    0 .        0 .
      1          0
```

However, not all possible bit patterns will lead to valid solutions; take this example:

```
2 . . . .    X 0 0 1 1
  2 . . .      2 . . .    2 . . .    X 0 1 1
    2 . .        2 . .      2 . .      2 . .    2 . .
      2 .          1 .        1 .        0 .      0 .
        2            1          1          0        0
```

where we end up with a row that requires another 2 ones while both columns can no longer take any ones. The way to spot this situation is by looking at the list of required ones per column that is created by each option in the penultimate step:

```
pattern    required
 0 1 1  ->  2 0 0
 1 0 1  ->  1 1 0
 1 1 0  ->  1 0 1
```

If the first value in the list is x, then there must be at least x non-zero values after it; which is false for the first of the three options.

*(There is room for optimization here: in a count list like `1,1,0,6,0,2,1,1` there are only 2 non-zero values before the 6, which means that the 6 will be decremented at most 2 times, so its minimum value when it becomes the first element will be 4; however, there are only 3 non-zero values after it, so at this stage you already know this list will not lead to any valid solutions. Checking this would add to the code complexity, so I'm not sure whether that would lead to an improvement in execution speed.)*

So the complete algorithm for (n,m) starts with:

> - Create an n-sized list with all values set to m (count of ones required per group).
> - Generate all bit patterns of size n-1 with m ones; for each of these:
>
>   - Subtract the pattern from a copy of the count list (without the first element).
>   - Recurse with the pattern and the copy of the count list.

and the recursive steps after that are:

> - Receive the sequence so far, and a count list.
> - The length of the count list is n, and its first element is m.
> - Let k be the number of non-zero values in the count list (without the first element).
> - Generate all bit pattern of size k with m ones; for each of these:
>
>   - Create a 0-filled list sized n-1.
>   - Distribute the bit pattern over it, skipping the columns with a zero count.
>   - Add the value list to the sequence so far.
>   - Subtract the value list from a copy of the count list (without the first element).
>   - If the first value in the copy of the count list is greater than the number of non-zeros after it, skip this pattern.
>   - At the deepest recursion level, store the sequence, or else:
>   - Recurse with the sequence so far, and the copy of the count list.

---

Here's a code snippet as a proof of concept; in a serious language, and using integers instead of arrays for the bitmaps, this should be much faster:

```js
function generate(n, m) {
    // if ((n % 2) && (m % 2)) return; // to catch (3,1)
    var counts = [], pattern = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        counts.push(m);
        pattern.push(i < m ? 1 : 0);
    }
    do {
        var c_copy = counts.slice();
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) c_copy[i] -= pattern[i];
        recurse(pattern, c_copy);
    }
    while (revLexi(pattern));
}

function recurse(sequence, counts) {
    var n = counts.length, m = counts.shift(), k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) if (counts[i]) ++k;
    var pattern = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) pattern.push(i < m ? 1 : 0);
    do {
        var values = [], pos = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (counts[i]) values.push(pattern[pos++]);
            else values.push(0);
        }
        var s_copy = sequence.concat(values);
        var c_copy = counts.slice();
        var nonzero = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            c_copy[i] -= values[i];
            if (i && c_copy[i]) ++nonzero;
        }
        if (c_copy[0] > nonzero) continue;
        if (n == 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < s_copy.length; i++) {
                document.write(["+ ", "&minus; "][s_copy[i]]);
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
        else recurse(s_copy, c_copy);
    }
    while (revLexi(pattern));
}

function revLexi(seq) { // reverse lexicographical because I had this lying around
    var max = true, pos = seq.length, set = 1;
    while (pos-- && (max || !seq[pos])) if (seq[pos]) ++set; else max = false;
    if (pos < 0) return false;
    seq[pos] = 0;
    while (++pos < seq.length) seq[pos] = set-- > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return true;
}

generate(5, 2);
```

---

Here are the number of results and the number of recursions for values of n up to 10, so you can compare them to check correctness. When n and m are both odd numbers, there are no valid results; this is calculated correctly, except in the case of (3,1); it is of course easy to catch these cases and return immediately.

```
 (n,m)            results        number of recursions

 (4,0)  (4,3)           1            2            2
 (4,1)  (4,2)           3            6            7

 (5,0)  (5,4)           1            3            3
 (5,1)  (5,3)           0           12           20
 (5,2)                 12           36

 (6,0)  (6,5)           1            4            4
 (6,1)  (6,4)          15           48           76
 (6,2)  (6,3)          70          226          269

 (7,0)  (7,6)           1            5            5
 (7,1)  (7,5)           0           99          257
 (7,2)  (7,4)         465        1,627        2,313
 (7,3)                  0        3,413

 (8,0)  (8,7)           1            6            6
 (8,1)  (8,6)         105          422        1,041
 (8,2)  (8,5)       3,507       13,180       23,302
 (8,3)  (8,4)      19,355       77,466       93,441

 (9,0)  (9,8)           1            7            7
 (9,1)  (9,7)           0          948        4,192
 (9,2)  (9,6)      30,016      119,896      270,707
 (9,3)  (9,5)           0    1,427,457    2,405,396
 (9,4)          1,024,380    4,851,650

(10,0) (10,9)           1            8            8
(10,1) (10,8)         945         4440        18930
(10,2) (10,7)     286,884    1,210,612    3,574,257
(10,3) (10,6)  11,180,820   47,559,340   88,725,087
(10,4) (10,5)  66,462,606  313,129,003  383,079,169
```

Comment: Wow - thanks for this answer! I'll go through it a bit later on and let you know if I manage to implement it.

Comment: @LukeCollins I tried a version of the optimization, but although it cut the number of recursions by a third, the added complexity made the algorithm much slower in real terms.

Comment: @LukeCollins Thanks. Did this turn out to be useful in Mathematica? (Also, can I suggest you edit the title of the question to better describe the mathematics you're doing, so that someone doing something similar can find the question? Mentioning "strings of +/-s with a specific property" is a bit vague.)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you really want all variants for large n,m values - number of them is tremendous large.

This problem is equivalent to generation of m-regular graphs (note that if we replace all 1's by zeros and all -1's by 1 - we can see adjacency matrix of graph. Regular graph - degrees of all vertices are equal to m).

[Here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/pdf/pub/FastGenRegGraphJGT.pdf) we can see that number of (18,4) regular graphs is about 10^9 and rises fast with n/m values. Article contains [link](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html) to program `genreg` intended for such graphs generation.  FTP links to code and executable don't work for me - perhaps too old.

**Upd:** [Here is](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Markus_Meringer/publication/307964656_GENREG_Original_Source_Package/data/57d3dbde08ae601b39a72146/genreg.tar) another link to source (though 1996 year instead of paper's 1999)

Simple approach to generate one instance of regular graph is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142112/how-to-construct-a-k-regular-graph).

For small n/m values you can also try brute-force: fill the first row with m ones (there are C(n,m) variants and for every variants fill free places in the second row and so on)

Comment: Correct, I am generating what's called the Seidel adjacency matrix of a graph. I want to generate a graph on 74 vertices such that the matrix has precisely two eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, I would expect that brute force is applicable for n<10. I added link to genreg source. Hope it could help.

Comment: In truth I'm interested in generating [strongly regular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StronglyRegularGraph.html) graphs, which is a subset of regular graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Written in Wolfram Mathematica.

```
generate[n_, m_] := Module[{},
  x = Table[StringJoin["i", ToString[i], "j", ToString[j]],
    {j, 1, n}, {i, 2, n}];
  y = Transpose[x];
  MapThread[(x[[#, ;; #2]] = y[[#, ;; #2]]) &,
   {-Range[n - 1], Reverse@Range[n - 1]}];
  Clear @@ Names["i*"];
  z = ToExpression[x];
  Clear[s];
  s = Reduce[Join[Total@# == m & /@ z,
     0 <= # <= 1 & /@ Union[Flatten@z]],
    Union@Flatten[z], Integers];
  Clear[t, u, v];
  Array[(t[#] = 
      Partition[Flatten[z] /.
         ToRules[s[[#]]], n - 1] /.
       {1 -> -1, 0 -> 1}) &, Length[s]];
  Array[Function[a,
    (u[a] = StringJoin[Flatten[MapThread[
          Take[#, 1 - #2] &,
          {t[a], Reverse[Range[n]]}]] /.
        {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"}])], Length[s]];
  Array[Function[a,
    (v[a] = MapThread[Insert[#, 0, #2] &,
       {t[a], Range[n]}])], Length[s]]]

Timing[generate[9, 4];]
Length[s]
```

> ```
> {202.208, Null}
> 1024380
> ```

The program takes 202 seconds to generate 1,024,380 solutions. E.g. the last one

```
u[1024380]
```

> ```
> ----++++---++++-+-+++++-++++--------
> ```

```
v[1024380]
```

> ```
>  0  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   
> -1   0  -1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   
> -1  -1   0  -1   1  -1   1   1   1   
> -1  -1  -1   0   1   1  -1   1   1   
> -1  -1   1   1   0   1   1  -1  -1   
>  1   1  -1   1   1   0  -1  -1  -1   
>  1   1   1  -1   1  -1   0  -1  -1   
>  1   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   0  -1   
>  1   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1   0
> ```

and the first ten strings

```
u /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> ++++----+++----+-+-----+----++++++++
> ++++----+++----+-+------+--+-+++++++
> ++++----+++----+-+-------+-++-++++++
> ++++----+++----+--+---+-----++++++++
> ++++----+++----+---+--+----+-+++++++
> ++++----+++----+----+-+----++-++++++
> ++++----+++----+--+-----+-+--+++++++ 
> ++++----+++----+--+------++-+-++++++
> ++++----+++----+---+---+--+--+++++++
> ```

Comment: @m69 I got 465 for (7,2) and (7,4) and zero for (7,3).